# How do I fix 'RenderFlex overflowed by 283 pixels on the bottom' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The error occurs in a screen where I am trying to render a list of contributions. I have tried a number of things (listed below), none of which works.

1. Wrapping my column widget with Expanded()
2. Wrapping my Column widget with Flexible()
3. Wrapping my Listview.builder() with SingleScrollView() then adding `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzdmR.png)

I have a contributions screen with contains a Lisview.builder()

This is my contributions screen

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Chamas'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: CustomFloatingActionButton(
        buttonLabel: 'Contribute +',
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.22,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: widget.availableChamas.length, // number of cards
              controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
              onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
              /*** Begin snapping chama cards */
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                return Transform.scale(
                  scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 6,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, // Card backgound color
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          stops: [0.1, 0.9],
                          colors: [Colors.indigo, Colors.teal],
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: ChamaCard(
                        id: widget.availableChamas[i].id,
                        name: widget.availableChamas[i].name,
                        totalMembers: widget.availableChamas[i].totalMembers,
                        totalContributions: widget.availableChamas[i].totalContributions,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
                /*** End snapping chama cards */
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'All my chamas',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.red[900]),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      size: 17,
                      color: Colors.red[900],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('My', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20)),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Contributions',
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Text(
                              'to this chama',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[800]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ChamaListItem(
                      id: widget.availableContributions[index].id,
                      amount: widget.availableContributions[index].amount,
                      contributionDate: widget.availableContributions[index].contributionDate,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: widget.availableContributions.length,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my ChamaListItem widget which simply holds a single contribution card. This is what I am iterating to build a scrollable list in my Listview.builder()

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4,
      shadowColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Date',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Text(
                  '$contributionDate',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[900]),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Kes'),
                SizedBox(width: 1),
                Text(
                  '$amount',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the error thrown in the console

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
Reloaded 5 of 566 libraries in 1,183ms.

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 283 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///Users/Steve/StudioProjects/m_chama/lib/screens/myChamas.dart:35:13
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#3a382 relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 105.5); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=697.5)
...  size: Size(392.7, 697.5)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error from the console, So we can track down exactly where the issue is occurring?

Comment: Okay @RohanThacker I have added console error to description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Column` widget with `SingleChiledScrollView`

Comment: Thank you, this actually works. However, is there a way to keep the top horizontal cards static and only scroll the listview builder?

Comment: I know I can wrap the listview builder with a SingleChildScrollView and then wrap that with a container that has a fixed height. But we do not know the height of our users devices, which means our app will behave differently on different devices. Example:

`Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      /// list gere
                  ),
                )`
Another disadvantage with this approach is that container height can never exceed screen real estate.